# React Admin white page on EditView

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm working with React Admin, I have and EditView, when I redirect the user from the table to the EditView, it works perfect, BUT, when I push f5 and recharge the site, the same view shows a white page:

[image]

I think this has to be with the Resource definition, I have define this:

```
 <Resource name="books" list={BooksList} edit={BooksEdit} />
```

The fetch to the api works fine, for that reason I think that the problem is something that I dont understand on the Edit, Show config.

I dont have Show view, because when I click on the table, I want the edit view without more clicks.

Answer (score 0):

It is because when you refresh the page, the components return to their first state. The state that you're creating is not being saved anywhere, so when you hit F5 the state "goes back to the beginning".

Comment: The it should show an empty form. 

It has no sense, because when I refresh it makes the fetch data, it should take the data and fill the form.